# ArrayList в ArrayList. Как это понять?

Tags: java, массивы, list, arraylist

Как работать с этим:

```java
private List<List<Object>> data;
```

Как это понять?

Есть ячейки листа, в его ячейках находятся другие ячейки другого листа?

А уж в этой ячейке уже лежат объекты?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List<List<Object>> data` - это двумерный массив. Проще всего представить себе это как обычную таблицу, у которой есть строки и столбцы.

Так что, `data.get(0)` - это первая строка. `data.get(0).get(0)` - первая строка и первый столбец, то есть это `[0;0]` ячейка в таблице.